# XSL XML transformation, changing namespace value

Tags: java, xslt, namespaces, xslt-1.0, saxon

i'm trying to remove some elements from xml using xsl and also to **change a namespace value** declared in sub1 element. The problem is, when i change the namespace value, the old namespace declaration is inserted into a child element (sub2 in the example), how can i change the code to prevent it?

I made this example because i cannot show the real code

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet version="1.0" href="test.xsl"?>
<lamp:rootElement xmlns:lamp="adgfdgfhdsadfse">
<pref:sub1 ID="someId" xmlns:pref="http://www.myMountain.org/blabla">
    <pref:sub2>
    Today is tuesday
        <pref:sub3 att="someAttribute">
        Some text
            <pref:sub4>
                <pref:emptyElement/>
            </pref:sub4>
        </pref:sub3>
    </pref:sub2>
</pref:sub1>
</lamp:rootElement>
```

test.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:oldPref="http://www.myMountain.org/blabla"
xmlns:pref="http://www.myHill.org/blabla"
exclude-result-prefixes="oldPref">

<!-- For deleting element "sub4" -->
<xsl:template match="oldPref:sub1/oldPref:sub2/oldPref:sub3/oldPref:sub4"/>

<!-- Now i'm replacing the value of "pref" namespace (by creating a new element) -->
<xsl:template match="oldPref:sub1">

    <pref:sub1>
        <!-- Now i'm copying the elements from old "sub1" to the new one -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </pref:sub1>

</xsl:template>

<!-- Now im copying the rest of the xml file -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

wrong result that i get result.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet version="1.0" href="test.xsl"?>
<lamp:rootElement xmlns:lamp="adgfdgfhdsadfse">
<pref:sub1 xmlns:pref="http://www.myHill.org/blabla" ID="someId">
    <pref:sub2 xmlns:pref="http://www.myMountain.org/blabla">
    Today is tuesday
        <pref:sub3 att="someAttribute">
        Some text

        </pref:sub3>
    </pref:sub2>
</pref:sub1>
</lamp:rootElement>
```

desired result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet version="1.0" href="test.xsl"?>
<lamp:rootElement xmlns:lamp="adgfdgfhdsadfse">
<pref:sub1 xmlns:pref="http://www.myHill.org/blabla" ID="someId">
    <pref:sub2>
    Today is tuesday
        <pref:sub3 att="someAttribute">
        Some text

        </pref:sub3>
    </pref:sub2>
</pref:sub1>
</lamp:rootElement>
```

My saxon

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.4
Project-Name: Saxon-HE
Created-By: 1.7.0_05-b06 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: net.sf.saxon.Transform
```

This is the command i'm using

```
java net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:test.xml -xsl:test.xsl -o:result.xml
```

Comment: Note that Saxon HE supports XSLT 2.0, so it doesn't make a lot of sense to tag a question as both "saxon" and "xslt-1.0"

Comment: And if you want to know which Saxon version you are using, run it from the command line with the -t option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are changing the namespace on `pref:sub1`, but not on any of the other `pref:` elements. You need something more general:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:oldPref="http://www.myMountain.org/blabla"
                xmlns:pref="http://www.myHill.org/blabla"
                exclude-result-prefixes="oldPref">

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="oldPref:*">
    <xsl:element name="pref:{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="oldPref:sub4" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<?xml-stylesheet version="1.0" href="test.xsl"?>
<lamp:rootElement xmlns:lamp="adgfdgfhdsadfse">
  <pref:sub1 ID="someId" xmlns:pref="http://www.myHill.org/blabla">
    <pref:sub2>
      Today is tuesday
      <pref:sub3 att="someAttribute">
        Some text

      </pref:sub3>
    </pref:sub2>
  </pref:sub1>
</lamp:rootElement>
```